# Can multiple runbooks run simultaneously in an azure automation account?

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-runbook

Can multiple runbooks run simultaneously in an `azure automation account`? If yes, how many?

I have checked the microsoft documentation but I couldn't find anything relevant.
From my experience, i have seen a runbook can be completed while another is in running status.
[image]

But I see that the `runbooks` are queued. Is there a limit for simultaneous runs? If yes, can it be increased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can multiple runbooks run simultaneously in an azure automation account? If yes, how many?

Yes, more specifically, it should be runbook jobs instead of runbooks, starting a runbook in Azure Automation creates a job, which is a single execution instance of the runbook.

And runbooks in Azure Automation can run on either an Azure sandbox or a [Hybrid Runbook Worker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker), they have different limits, if you start your runbook in the portal, it uses Azure sandbox.

For Azure sandbox:

[image]

For Hybrid Runbook Worker:

[image]

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#automation-limits

> But I see that the runbooks are queued.

The status `Queued` does not mean the runbooks are waiting for the running jobs to complete, Azure Automation assigns a worker to run each job during runbook execution, they are just waiting for the worker.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-execution#job-statuses

[image]

> Is there a limit for simultaneous runs?

Yes, as mentioned above, there is a limit `200` for simultaneous runs per automation account for Azure sandbox.

> If yes, can it be increased?

No, it cannot be increased.